# How do you add two binary numbers stored within linked lists, and merge them into one linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list, binary

I have created two linked lists containing binary numbers and have tried to create a function to add them and return them in top. It accepts a list top, n1 (which contains the first binary number) and n2 (contains the second). It works flawlessly with a normal array however with linked lists it gives the wrong result.

```
Node *BinaryAddition(Node *top, Node *n1, Node *n2)
{
    Node *curr1= (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    curr1=n1;
    Node *curr2=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    curr2=n2;

    int sum = 0;
    int remainder = 0;

    while(curr1!=NULL && curr2!=NULL)
    {
        while((curr1->data != 0 || curr2->data != 0))
        {
            sum=((curr1->data %10) + (curr2->data %10) + remainder)%2;
            top=InsertAtHead(top, sum);
            remainder=((curr1->data%10) + (curr2->data%10) + remainder)/2;
            curr1->data=(curr1->data)/10;
            curr2->data=(curr2->data)/10;
        }

        if(remainder!=0)
        {
            sum=remainder;
            top=InsertAtHead(top,sum);
        }


        curr1=curr1->next;
        curr2=curr2->next;
    }
    return top;
}
```

Comment: A couple points with your code; malloc shouldn't be used in C++ as it won't call constructors and has no type safety, and you have a memory leak here: `curr1=n1;` because `cirr1` was just assigned allocated memory which is now inaccessible

Comment: It doesn't look like any binary addition I'm familiar with. All the literal `10` values sprinkled around in this code makes me think of ... decimal. Yes, I know, a programmer is one who knows that the binary numeral system has 10 digits, but still.

Answer (score -1):

The usual solution is to separate the linked list operations and the addition. Your function tries to do both, which makes it very unclear.

I'd expect a method `List add(List const& l1, List const& l2)`.

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
curr1 = n1;
```

to

```
*curr1 = *n1;
```

Similar with curr2.